# Is there a way to use Subresource Integrity (SRI) for the componetPreload.js?

Tags: sapui5, subresource-integrity

For security reasons some hacker manipulates code inside the 'componentPreload.js'. He uses Charles for that. I am searching now a way to check the integrity of this file. With the 'Subresource Integrity' mechanism, it is only possible to check the integrity of the sap-ui-core.js.

There is an article from Tobias Hofmann https://www.itsfullofstars.de/2021/07/ui5-resource-integrity/
but it doesn't solve my problem.

I want to have a mechnism to check the comopnentPreload is the same on CND side and of the client side.
Is there a way to do this?